# Does isomorphism of the underlying module/abelian group structure imply an isomorphism of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $A$ and $B$ be $R$-algebras. If $f: A\to B$ is a homomorphism of $R$-algebras, such that one can show that $f$ is an isomorphism of the underlying $R$-modules, is $f$ an isomorphism of $R$-algebras?

I would say that if $f$ is a homomorphism of $R$-algebras and we know that $f$ is an isomorphism of the underlying abelian groups of $A$ and $B$, that should suffice to conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism of $R$-algebras because $f$ would be a bijective algebra homomorphism which is the definition of an isomorphism of algebras.

Comment: Since $f$ is an isomorphism (of modules), it has an inverse and it seems to me that this inverse satisfies $f^{-1}(cd)=f^{-1}(c)f^{-1}(d)$ for all $c,d\in B$ (because $f$ is a morphism of algebras).

Comment: Yes, I agree. Moreover, I believe that it is sufficient that $f$ is an isomorphism of the underlying abelian additive groups $A$ and $B$. In this case $f$ would be a bijective $R$-algebra homomorphism which by definition is an $R$-algebra isomorphism.

Comment: A bijective $R$-algebra homomorphism is necessarily an isomorphism. An isomorphism of $R$-modules is necessarily bijective. (I'm assuming your definition of "isomorphism" is "there exists a homomorphism $g$ such that $fg=\mathrm{id}$ and $gf=\mathrm{id}$").

Comment: An isomorphism of $R$-algebras is necessarily bijective. And a bijective homomorphism of algebras is necessarily an isomorphism, no? So, basically you agree with what I wrote in my post and in my comments, don't you?

Comment: I don't understand what your doubt is. Unless you have a very weird definition of "isomorphism". The two standard definitions are "a homomorphism that has an inverse which is also a homomorphism" and "a homomorphism that is bijective on underlying sets." In either case, the fact that a bijective homomorphism is necessarily an isomorphism is either obvious or a rather easy consequence.